# Enumerated type as input or output

Tags: enums, verilog, system-verilog

In Systemveilog, is there any way that one can pass an enum type variable to other modules? That is, to define an enum type variable as either input or output. Is there any example available?

Comment: IEEE Std 1800-2012: https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you need to use a `typedef` in a common package to make the enums assignment compatible. Then you can use an enum in a port just like any data type.

```
package myCommon;
  typedef enum {ONE,TWO} e_t;
endpackage
module first import myCommon::*; (output e_t p1);
endmodule
module second import myCommon::*; (input e_t p2);
endmodule
module top;
  import myCommon::*;
  e_t e;
  first f(.p1(e));
  second s(.p2(e));
endmodule
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I think you meant typedef enum {ONE,TWO} e_t; in the code. By the way, any idea how this thing will be synthesized? I want to use this enum type to indicate different states. In an old style programming, I can use register and parameter to do the state label. I know it will be synthesized as registers. But for this, I have no idea.

Comment: example corrected. I believe you can use an enum variable as a state register the same way you used to use parameters as values with a variable. Except you now have type safety as wll as the additional enum methods to manipulate the state.